# Writing Windows batch Chef recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I have not done chef before. Does the following code look correct?

```
batch 'windows_batch' do
    code <<-EOH
          C:\bootstrap\SInstaller.exe /S /APIKEY=hththfthtfdh
    EOH
end
```

The command is to silently install SInstaller.exe

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using `powershell_script` instead

```
powershell_script 'windows_batch' do
    code <<-EOH
        Start-Process "cmd.exe"  "/c C:\\bootstrap\\SInstaller.exe /S /APIKEY=hththfthtfdh"
    EOH
end
```

This script runs new instance of cmd process and runs command `C:\bootstrap\SInstaller.exe /S /APIKEY=hththfthtfdh` in it.

For me, `batch` is sometimes a little buggy.

Try using it and tell me if it works!

If you still prefer using `batch` resource, you have to write paths with \, like
`C:\\bootstrap\\SInstaller.exe /S /APIKEY=hththfthtfdh` or you will have error

```
Invalid escape character syntax
      C:\bootstrap\SInstaller.exe /S /APIKEY=hththfthtfdh
                   ^
```

Rest of your code seems OK to me.